# What does slice[0:0] do in Go?

Tags: go

I recently saw the following code in a Golang markdown parser:

```golang
    blankLines := make([]lineStat, 0, 128)
    isBlank := false
    for { // process blocks separated by blank lines
        _, lines, ok := reader.SkipBlankLines()
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        lineNum, _ := reader.Position()
        if lines != 0 {
            blankLines = blankLines[0:0]
            l := len(pc.OpenedBlocks())
            for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
                blankLines = append(blankLines, lineStat{lineNum - 1, i, lines != 0})
            }
        }
```

I'm confused as to what `blankLines = blankLines[0:0]` does. Is this a way to prepend to an array?

Comment: That is not an array, you are dealing with slices here

Comment: This is considered a basic concept of the language, covered [here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) for example.

Comment: Oh whoops -- I meant slice. I was just confused b/c it felt like there was no purpose to creating an empty slice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This slicing `[0:0]` creates a slice that has the same backing array, but zero length. All it's really doing is "resetting" the `len` on the slice so that the underlying array can be re-used. It avoids the allocation that may be required if a completely new slice was created for each iteration.

Comment: the phrase `resetting the len on the slice so that the underlying array can be re-used` is not correct, it literally create new slice with 0 len and same capacity https://goplay.space/#Cy78GySMlAk

Comment: @HieuVo your example shows `slice[:0:0]`, while this question is about `slice[0:0]`. Due to the extra `:` character, these are different operations with different results.